# slack bolt callback is not working Python I have two listsers

Tags: python-3.x, slack-block-kit, slack-bolt

I have two listeners. Whenever the message is sent to slack channel, handle_message_events to be invoked and timer to be started. If message contains confirm_button and its clicked then it should invoke confirm_button_click.

Its listening to some messages in the channel i.e invoking receive_message method for every message on the channel but for some messages does not invoke the method. Behaviour is inconsistent.
I have added all the permissions to App chat:write, channel:message. App is the member of the channel.

Please help me in resolving the issue. Thank you

```
app = App(token = slack_bot_token, ignoring_self_events_enabled=False)
@app.evnt("message")
 def receive_message(body, say):
     pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple listeners for message events, only the first matched one is invoked. If you want to do something for all message events, you can have a global middleware. Another approach would be to move those logic into a single message event listener and dispatch events inside the function.